# Heroku push error: "Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5) from rubygems repository" AFTER update to Rails 6.1.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep receiving this error `Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5) from rubygems repository` when pushing to heroku.

I read the [resolved issue on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41750) where the Rails team swapped the dependency on ActiveStorage from mimemagic to mini_mime. So I did what was recommended and upgraded my app from Rails 6.0.3 to 6.1.3.2. My Gemfile now has `gem 'rails', '>=6.1.3.2'`.

I ran `bundle update` which updated all the gems and I did a `bundle uninstall mimemagic` for good measure.

I verified in my Gemfile.lock that there is no longer a reference to mime_magic. Instead, I can see that activestorage has the updated dependency on mini_mime:

```rb
activestorage (6.1.3.2)
  actionpack (= 6.1.3.2)
  activejob (= 6.1.3.2)
  activerecord (= 6.1.3.2)
  activesupport (= 6.1.3.2)
  marcel (~> 1.0.0)
  mini_mime (~> 1.0.2)
```

All changes are committed in the repo. However, when I deploy to Heroku via `git push heroku main`, I still receive this `Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5) from rubygems repository` error. How can there be a dependency when all gems were updated and no longer reference it, and its no longer present in both my local machine or Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was porting my existing app to heroku, so I created a separate branch called `heroku` to make the changes. I wanted to test first-time deployment to heroku *before* merging with my main branch.

So I was running `$ git push heroku main` expecting to push my local heroku branch to Heroku. Instead, it was pushing my main branch, which did not have the updated Rails gems.

Lesson learned, running `$ git push heroku main` pushes your **main** branch even if you are currently on a different branch.

I went into the settings for my Heroku app and did a manual build/deploy from Github of my `heroku` branch. App built and deployed successfully.

Comment: Or you could have done a `git push heroku <local-branch>:main`